# Finding solution of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> By recalling that $\cos (\alpha +\beta)=\cos \alpha \cos \beta -\sin \alpha \sin \beta\\ 
>  \sin (\alpha +\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta +\cos \alpha \sin \beta $
>
> Find the general solution $x_{n+2}-x_n=\sin (n)$.

---

Now it's easily see that we get $x_2-x_0=\sin 0\\ x_2-x_1=\sin 1\\x_4-x_2=\sin 2\\... \\x_{n+1}-x_{n-1}=\sin (n-1)\\x_{n+2}-x_n=\sin (n)$

summing all we get 
$x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}-x_0-x_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sin i$ 
but after that i can't go further ...
thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sin k=\Im\left\{\sum_{k=0}^n e^{jk}\right\}$$which is a simple geometric series where $\Im\{\cdot\}$ denotes the imaginary part of a complex number.

**Remark**

It is better to apply telescopic series once on $x_{2n}$ as $$x_{2n+2}-x_{2n}=\sin 2n$$to obtain $$x_{2n+2}=x_{0}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin 2k$$and once on $x_{2n+1}$ to obtain $$x_{2n+1}=x_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin (2k+1)$$

Comment: but LHS is $x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}$

Comment: I started by summing up $x_{n+2}-x_n=\sin n$ so that I can use the telescopic series

Comment: After telescoping $x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}-x_0-x_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sin i$

Comment: i don't know using this how find a general solution ...

Comment: I added more detail. Hope it help.